# MSMQ ReceiveById failing

Tags: c#, msmq

I have the following code

```
public class MsmqQueueProvider : IQueueProvider
{
    public void VeryfyIsAvailable(string name)
    {
        var queueAddress = string.Format(@" .\private$\{0}", name);
        var message = "There was a problem while starting the NEasyMessaging.";

        if (MessageQueue.Exists(queueAddress))
        {
            using (var queue = new MessageQueue(queueAddress))
            {
                if (queue.CanWrite && queue.CanRead) return;

                if (queue.CanRead == false)
                {
                    message += string.Format("Queue {0} is reachable but not readable", queueAddress);

                    throw new QueueProviderProviderException(message);
                }

                message += string.Format("Queue {0} is reachable but not writable", queueAddress);

                throw new QueueProviderProviderException(message);
            }
        }

        message += string.Format("Queue {0} cannot be found", queueAddress);

        throw new QueueProviderProviderException(message);
    }

    public QueueMessage Peek(string queueName)
    {
        var queue = new MessageQueue(string.Format(@" .\private$\{0}", queueName), QueueAccessMode.Peek);
        var message = queue.Peek();

        // ReSharper disable once PossibleNullReferenceException
        return new QueueMessage(message.Id, message.Label, new StreamReader(message.BodyStream).ReadToEnd());
    }

    public QueueMessage Receive(string queueName)
    {
        var queue = new MessageQueue(string.Format(@" .\private$\{0}", queueName), QueueAccessMode.Receive);
        var message = queue.Receive(MessageQueueTransactionType.Automatic);

        // ReSharper disable once PossibleNullReferenceException
        return new QueueMessage(message.Id, message.Label, new StreamReader(message.BodyStream).ReadToEnd());
    }

    public QueueMessage ReceiveById(string queueName, string messageId)
    {
        var queue = new MessageQueue(string.Format(@" .\private$\{0}", queueName), QueueAccessMode.Receive);
        var message = queue.ReceiveById(messageId, MessageQueueTransactionType.Automatic);

        // ReSharper disable once PossibleNullReferenceException
        return new QueueMessage(message.Id, message.Label, new StreamReader(message.BodyStream).ReadToEnd());
    }

    public void QueueMessage(string messageContent, string messageName, string queueName)
    {
        var queueAddress = string.Format(@" .\private$\{0}", queueName);

        using (var streamReader = new StringReader(messageContent))
        {
            var message = new Message
            {
                TimeToBeReceived = Message.InfiniteTimeout,
                TimeToReachQueue = Message.InfiniteTimeout,
                Label = messageName,
                UseAuthentication = false,
                Recoverable = true
            };

            using (var queue = new MessageQueue(queueAddress, QueueAccessMode.Send))
            {
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(message.BodyStream))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
                    streamWriter.Flush();

                    queue.Send(message, MessageQueueTransactionType.Automatic);
                }

                queue.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}


public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private TransactionScope _transaction;


    public void Start()
    {
        var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions
        {
            Timeout = TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout
        };

        _transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, transactionOptions);
    }

    public void CompletedWithSuccess()
    {
        if (Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.Status == TransactionStatus.Active)
        {
            _transaction.Complete();
        }

        _transaction.Dispose();
    }

    public void CompletedWithFail()
    {
        _transaction.Dispose();
    }
}


public sealed partial class Service : ServiceBase
{
    private readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Service));
    private readonly ManualResetEvent _shutdownEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private Thread _workerThread;
    private IQueueProvider _queueProvider;
    private IEndpointConfiguration _configuration;
    private IContainer _container;

    public Service()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ServiceName = "";
        EventLog.Log = "";
    }


    public void Init()
    {
        var endpointBootstrap = new EndpointBootstrap();

        endpointBootstrap.Initialize();

        _container = endpointBootstrap.IocContainer;
        _queueProvider = _container.Resolve<IQueueProvider>();
        _configuration = _container.Resolve<IEndpointConfiguration>();

        _workerThread = new Thread(DoWork) { Name = "Worker Thread", IsBackground = true };

        _workerThread.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Init();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _shutdownEvent.Set();

        if (!_workerThread.Join(3000))
        {
            _workerThread.Abort();
        }
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
        {
            var queueMessage = _queueProvider.Peek(_configuration.QueueName);

            try
            {
                ProcessMessage(queueMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.Error(ex);

                MoveMessageToErrorQueue(queueMessage.Id);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ProcessMessage(QueueMessage message)
    {
        using (var dependencyScope = _container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var unitOfWork = dependencyScope.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();

            unitOfWork.Start();

            var messageProcessor = new MessageProcessor(dependencyScope);

            try
            {
                messageProcessor.HandleMessage(message);

                _queueProvider.ReceiveById(_configuration.QueueName, message.Id);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.Error(ex);

                unitOfWork.CompletedWithFail();

                throw;
            }

            unitOfWork.CompletedWithSuccess();
        }
    }

    private void MoveMessageToErrorQueue(string messageId)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var dependencyScope = _container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                var unitOfWork = dependencyScope.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();

                unitOfWork.Start();

                var message = _queueProvider.ReceiveById(_configuration.QueueName, messageId);

                try
                {
                    _queueProvider.QueueMessage(message.Body, message.Name, _configuration.QueueErrorName);

                    unitOfWork.CompletedWithSuccess();
                }
                catch
                {
                    unitOfWork.CompletedWithFail();

                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.Error(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically my idea is simple at least on paper. Messages are taken from the queue just fine and on the dev machine everything works fine, the problem is when we deploy the code to our server (Windows 2008). If a message is not processed properly we remove the message from the queue and put it into a error queue, problem is, the method GetById cannot find the message:

```
private void MoveMessageToErrorQueue(string messageId)

var message = _queueProvider.ReceiveById(_configuration.QueueName, messageId);
```

It works fine on the dev boxes, but we just can find a way to fix this.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks

> UPDATE

Following Paul's comment:

Hi Paul, thanks for you help. Unfortunately unless I understood something wrong not even begin Received will do. Right now I pick a message from the queue and since there is only one thread reading from that queue if a later on receive the message by id, it seems logic for the message to still be there. So why I think I need to do the things they way I do. I peek the message, then create a transaction scope and do any processing, and of course any sql server sessions created during the execution will enroll that transaction. If something goes wrong during the message processing I need to rollback the changes done to the database and to do so I rollback the transaction, but I also need to put the failing message in a error queue. I can't do in just one transaction, remove the message from the queue try to process the message and if it fail put it into the error queue, because I still need to rollback the database changes.

Comment: so you get the message on the production machine, but can't find it later? or does it not arrive at all?

Comment: Hi Default. The message is there it must be. If during the message processing an exception is generated the transaction scope is rollback and a new transaction is created to move that message from one queue to another. The id of the message is the id of the message which was peaked just before the processing, so the message must be there, or at least that was what I though, after all peek just retrieves a copy of a message.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than Peek and then trying to get the message by id etc, why not just use BeginReceive/Receive or similar - that way you have the message already.

Just make sure you set the queue properties to include the body of the message (can't remember if that's the default for receive etc)

[MSDN - MessageQueue.BeginReceive Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43h44x53%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[MSDN - MessageQueue.Receive Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y918yfy2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

(Edit...)

If you want better visibility of your messages etc try downloading [MSMQ Inspector](http://viridissoftware.com.au/Products/MSMQInspector) (and yes it is my tool, I created it for these sorts of scenarios, I.e. What's going on?!)

If you use it, turn on "constant peek mode" and you should see massages coming in. I would also enable the journal for the queues you are using so as messages are processed you see them in the journal etc. perhaps double check that message id's are not being modified at times you do not expect etc. also, the different OS and MSMQ run times and setup may be causing different behaviours... Hard to say without running the code (which by the looks of what you posted we probably could!!)

PK :-)